# Show create date on video

Tags: video, adobe

How could I display the **create date** on videos using a video editing program, such like Adobe Premiere or After effects? Is it possible? I wan't do it **automatically**!

I have a bunch of videos and want to create a one large video with all the clips AND display the create date of each video OVER the clips.

I found this program, but it costs 80$ and is no option for me: http://dvmp.co.uk/

Comment: You can just add titles with the date. Or are you looking for a way to do it automatically?

Comment: You could use shell scripting to create a text file with the date, and then use ffmpeg to create a text overlay.

Comment: Yes, I want it do full automatically! I think it could be possible with some scripts, even maybe in After Effects? I would prefer to do this in one GUI based programm, not a command tool like ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to batch rename all your video files to match the creation date. There are a lot of free applications that can batch rename files for you. If you don't want to change the original file names of your clips, you should first make a copy of the files.

Every file name will need to be different, if you have a more than one clip recorded on the same day you will need to add a incrementing number of some other value to avoid duplicates.

Here I have used [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/tags_datetimecreated) to rename the files based on the meta data:

[image]

Import your footage into Premiere, arrange the clips how you like and add the 'Clip Name' effect from the Effects panel to one of your clips. An overlay on the video will display the file name.

If you want to hide the incrementing number and file extension at the end of the file name, you can either position the text far enough right that it is out of frame or use a rectangular mask to hide it.

Once you have adjusted the text in the way you like, copy the clip, select all the other clips in your sequence and use 'Paste Attributes' under the right-click menu to add the effect.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I guess this is THE solution for me. I already thought about renaming files based on the meta data. But the key was in adding "Clip name" effect to the clips.

Thank you! I hope this effect is available in Adobe Premiere CS6.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than render out one large video file, you can use your existing video files after a batch rename as Ambo100 mentioned previously with Advanced Renamer. A title rendering process, such as with Adobe Premiere or other editing platform, would also take time to render, especially if it's a large archive of clips.  The model below keeps them intact, and the original filename can be prefixed with your create date, which means you'd be able to keep the original filename included as a suffix.

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) can display the filename being played, which means you'd only need to merely save the playlist of your chosen video files versus making one video large file of all your videos.  If a user decides to stop the video once the desired video is found, VLC will also stop on that video listed in the playlist. A right-click will allow you to go to the file directly. I put nine-9s in my time for showing the video title, which equates to a video length of ~278-hours. 
[image: snapshot of VLC on Linux, showing the video panel under preferences and then choosing advanced]

Comment: Thank you. In my case I have to edit the clips anyway, so the solution with "clip name" effect is the best way.

And I have to play this video on TV where I don't have apps/programms like VLC :)